# "tensorflow/core/platform/posix/subprocess.cc:208] Start cannot fork() child process: Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have got this error while running `frcnn resnet 50` on my dataset of black and white images of Height:540 pixels and Width:800 pixels

```
tensorflow/core/platform/posix/subprocess.cc:208] Start cannot fork() child process: Cannot allocate memory
```

I am currently working on
K80 GPU (Google Cloud)
ubuntu 18.04

Any help regarding this error would be appreciated.

Comment: I am getting the same error on my local machine running Ubuntu 18.04 with TF2 and a GTX1080Ti.

Answer (score 2):

So, for me this got resolved when updating the Nvidia-Driver and switching to another CUDA and cudnn version. This is the combo that works for me (on a GTX1080Ti on Ubuntu 18.04):

- Python 3.7
- Nvidia-Driver 440.48.02
- CUDA 10.0.130
- cudnn 7.6.5.32
- Tensorflow-gpu 2.0

The same setup also works on a RTX2070 for me, but only if I add these code lines before my training loop:

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

Answer (score 1):

Enabling GPU memory growth helped for me

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth

Comment: Did not helped in my case (same issue on WSL2). Despite you can see TF started managing GPU memory dynamically, instead of allocating it all at startup.